# dll can be loaded on MAC os

Tags: java, macos, dll

Can we load dll on MAC os? what will be the the way to load dll from java in MAC os?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can load DLLs on OS X if you use [Wine](http://wiki.winehq.org/MacOSX). Loading them using just Java is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

Many operating systems have the concept of [shared libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_%28computing%29), but ofcourse the format etc. of such libraries is different on different operating systems.

DLLs (Dynamically Linked Libraries) are the Windows version of shared libraries. You cannot just use a DLL from a Windows machine on Mac OS, exactly like you cannot run a Windows application on Mac OS (or any other operating system).

Instead of trying to use a Windows DLL on Mac OS, you need to find a Mac OS-specific version of the native library that you are trying to use. Or if you have the source code, compile it into a Mac OS-native shared library. Shared libraries on Mac OS X have the extension `.so` (instead of `.dll`), which stands for "shared object".