# How to get dll equivalent file in macos from the installed application

Tags: java, macos, dll, dylib, linphone

I am new to java working on voip project linphone-desktop(cross-platform) project. I can generate the build files from the code available on the [github](https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-desktop). I can install linphone-Desktop application from the dmg file in my system but not sure from where I can find the dylib file to use it in my project to customize the linphone-desktop application as per my requirement.

Firstly, I have tried to use the dll file on my macos but later I have found that dll file on macos can be used through the [WINE](https://wiki.winehq.org/MacOS) only but I am using MacOS 10.15(Catelina) on which wine is not supported.

Listing few links which I have already visited.

https://www.chilkatsoft.com/java-loadlibrary-windows.asp

[dll can be loaded on MAC os](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243191/dll-can-be-loaded-on-mac-os)

[Loading DLL in java in UNIX system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13565280/loading-dll-in-java-in-unix-system)

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: DLL is Microsoft's implementation of the shared library concept for Windows, Dylib is Apple implementation for Mac and Apple package the applications executable and library are hidden with normal user.

Comment: WINE is Windows emulation translate layer for Mac and Linux but you can't expect 100% working. Why don't you build your own Linphone dylib for Mac from here: https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/liblinphone